# Is maxHistory property same in both SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy and TimeBasedRollingPolicy

Tags: logging, apache-nifi, logback, logback-groovy

I'm configuring Nifi rollback, and I came across **maxHistory** property. Right now, I'm in a confusion.

My understanding is that the *maxHistory*property in SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy says the number of hours. That means if i have added `<maxHistory>30</maxHistory>` it would mean 30 hours worth of logs are retained.

And *maxHistory*property in TimeBasedRollingPolicy, would mean 30 dayss worth of logs are retained.

Looking for some insights on this usecase.